# Cisco switch ios update without change license

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, license

I need the following ios switches to be updated to the latest "license-free" version to fix vulnerabilities:
C3560CX-12pd-S
C3650-48PS-E
C3850-12S-E
C3850-24T-E
C3850-12S

I didn't find any information on the Cisco website. Can anyone give a link or guide me to what version each one can be updated without needing a special license?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. I am not sure what you mean by "license-free" version. For Cisco products, you should have SmartNet in order to get license updates. Also, those switches are now EoS, and you should plan to replace them before they go EoL.

Comment: "license-free" == no smartnet. Contact TAC as per the instructions at the bottom of any of the publish vulnerabilities. (3560 and 3650 are EOL. 3850 might be.)